# WAMPSERVER/drupal complications

Tags: localhost, wamp, drupal, cms

I am brand new to web development...and getting Drupal running is a barrier no amount of Googling has helped solve.

When I install WAMPServer it works fine. When I tried to open my local domain name, I'm not redirected to profile selection page of Drupal installation.it leads me to the Wampserver localhost page. Here's the funny part, I tried opening localhost and it took me to bitnami's page (I tried using their xampp earlier without success)

Can anyone tell me why, how? I'm confused and hungry.

Comment: My advice, dump WAMP and use IIS. ;)

Comment: it's less complicated?

Comment: Depends on your POV.  To me, no it's not. To others, perhaps. Here's a guide for installing Drupal on IIS 7: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/install-drupal-on-iis, and also see https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/windows.  Using [the Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) to handle PHP makes it even easier. ;)

Comment: Then you probably did not uninstall XAMPP or Bitnami properly. Remember thay all install an Apache server and a MYSQL Server. Unless you know what you are doing having more than one installed will only confuse you.

Answer (score -1):

Move your c:/wamp/www/index.php file which is your Wamp localhost welcome page. Then put all your drupal files in that folder. The new index.php should be in the same www folder...